# curl request works from one server and give 403 on another

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to hit a url and get contents from it and below is the code

```
$url = 'http://uber.com';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) \ Chrome/24.0.1304.0 Safari/537.16', 
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 180,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 180 + 60,
CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'lang=en;'
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

It gives me the content when I execute the script on local server but while executing this on staging and production server, situated in US, it give 403-forbidden error. I also tested the same from another server in US and it works fine.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It works fine on my server too. Did you tried `https://www.uber.com` for the url ? Different user agent ? Can you give more details about the server (apache, nginx, mods, ...). I guess it's more related to a server configuration more than the php code.

Comment: `php_getinfo` returns a http_code 200. Although the redirect count is 1 ... that might be your issue there.

Comment: I tried "https://uber.com" but not with "www" it redirects to "https://www.uber.com", that is why redirect count is 1 and I believe I am also successfully following the redirect. PHP and curl versions are different on server but I believe that would not be an issue.

Comment: when I set option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true` the server script is working stops and give error: 'Curl Failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`. And the staging server is still giving 403 with this options as well. Is there any php or apache setting for this?

Comment: Just for update, the issue is with aws server. I tested this with another aws server, except the one I am having issue with, and found the same issue. While on other servers the curl call is success but on aws servers it returns 403.

Comment: @shaile Did you fix this?

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar : I ended up moving the code to another server from AWS at that time.